# Listar archivos en diréctorio .

Tags: python, terminal

Buenas , estoy buscando una manera de listar todos los archivos en un directorio x . Y que dicha función me devuelva una lista para poder manejar los nombres de los mismos. Alguna idea ? Con un módulo de la librería estándar o externo?

Comment: Hola limg21. Esto es relativamente básico. ¿Has hecho algún tipo de búsqueda al respecto? Un googleo fugaz me devuelve buenas entradas. Compare tu código y te ayudaremos en dudas concretas

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la librería [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.listdir#os.listdir) que lista el contenido del directorio actual.

```
for nombreArchivo in os.listdir("."):
    if nombreArchivo.endswith(".*"):
        nombreArchivo (name)
```

Para meterlo en una lista

```
lista = [
    nombreArchivo for nombreArchivo in os.listdir(".") 
    if nombreArchivo.endswith(".*")
]
```

O por ejemplo:

```
import os

# Abrir un archivo
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# Esto va a imprimir todos los archivos del directorio
for file in dirs:
   print file
```